# "Module not found" when deploying React app to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, node-modules

When I try to deploy my React app (made with create-react-app) to Heroku (using create-react-app-buildpack) I get the following error:

```
Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in 
'/tmp/build_049d73accaf035b451adf36ac44318d3/src/components'
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-128-generic
npm ERR! argv 
"/tmp/build_049d73accaf035b451adf36ac44318d3/.heroku/node/bin/node" 
"/tmp/build_049d73accaf035b451adf36ac44318d3/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "run" 
"build"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! life-quality-data@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

When testing on my computer everything works. I also have jQuery added as a dependency in *package.json*:

```
{
  "name": "life-quality-data",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "dns": "^0.2.2",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.12",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I think I might be missing a line. Also, could it be the *.gitignore*? Because on GitHub the node modules are being ignored.

Comment: Heroku does not install the packages for you. As part of your deployment did you consult the Heroku documentation about the right way to deploy a React app?

Comment: do `npm install ` during the deployment.No environment/platform do it for you.It should be part of deployment script(automation)

Comment: The create-react-app repo brought me to the instructions [here](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration). I followed them, but it fails to deploy. It's my first time using Heroku, I don't know how to `npm install` during the deployment.

Comment: Can you try adding a build of webpack before u deploy. Follow this link. Read the quick start section. https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack/blob/master/README.md

Comment: What fixed it for me was updating my master : git add -A, git commit -m "foobar", git push origin master, git push heroku master.  Not sure if you are also using this workflow however.